# Chart.js scatter chart stops working after extending to multiple datasets

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to build a line chart displaying temperature data on y axis and dates on x axis in an Angular 5 app using Chart.js. I have data from five cities and would like to plot all on one chart. Generating the chart goes well when using just one city's data, but expanding to include other cities fails.

I use this to generate the dataset from the data I pull from my API:

```
private createDataset(observations) {
    let temperatures = observations.map(obs => obs.temperature);
    let dates = observations.map(obs => obs.date);

    let data = [];
    temperatures.forEach((temperature, i) => {
      data.push({
        x: dates[i],
        y: temperature,
      });
    });

    return { data: data, showLine: true };
  }
```

And this to create a chart with a single dataset (works):

```
ngOnInit() {

  // No need for this with single dataset
  this.loaded = true;

  this.observationService.getHelsinki()
    .subscribe(observations => {
      let data = {
        datasets: [this.createDataset(observations)],
      };

      let options = {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
          }],
        },
      };

      this.chart = new Chart('temperatureChart', { type: 'scatter', data: data, options: options });
    });

}
```

Finally, I try to extend to all datasets like so:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.locationService.getAll()
    .subscribe((locations: any) => {
      this.loaded = false;
      let datasets = [];

      locations.forEach((location: any) => {
        this.observationService.getAllByLocation(location)
          .subscribe(observations => {
            datasets.push(this.createDataset(observations));
          });
      });

      let data = {
        datasets: datasets,
      };

      let options = {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
          }],
        },
      };

      this.chart = new Chart('temperatureChart', { type: 'scatter', data: data, options: options });
      this.loaded = true;
    });

}
```

For template, I use:

```
<div *ngIf="chart" [hidden]="!loaded">
  <canvas id="temperatureChart">
    {{ chart }}
  </canvas>
</div>
```

The variable `this.loaded` is used, possibly as a hack, to get rid of `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of null` when loading the page. When trying to use multiple datasets I either get this error and no chart at all, or no error and an empty chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Chart.js looks pretty awesome, so I guess I don't just get something here. Please note that I use the `{ x: ..., y: ... }` objects to represent data because the observations will be at different times and thus it's not possible to have a single `labels` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly out of scope, since the solution below does not use the data structure in my original question. However, as I believe my original method was much flawed in that it used nested API requests, I'm posting this answer that I believe achieves what I'm trying to do in a good manner.

My backend uses MongoDB, and this aggregation yielded a suitable data structure:

```
Observation.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$location.name",
    temperatures: {
      $push: { "temperature": "$temperature" },
    },
    dates: {
      $push: { "date": "$date" },
    },
  }
}]);
```

*(N.B., `$location.name` takes unique values so I'm using it as `$group._id` to strip a few lines of code.)*

With that, it became straightforward to create the chart like so:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.observationService.getAllGrouped()
    .subscribe((locations: any) => {
      let datasets = [];

      locations.forEach(location => {
        let temperatures = location.temperatures.map(t => t.temperature);
        let dates = location.dates.map(d => d.date);
        let data = [];

        temperatures.forEach((temperature, i) => {
          data.push({ x: dates[i], y: temperature });
        });

        datasets.push({ label: location._id, data: data });
      });

      const data = { datasets: datasets };
      const options = {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
          }],
        },
      };

      this.chart = new Chart('canvas', { type: 'scatter', data: data, options: options });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a chart after component's view is initialized, thus use ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit.

Update:
In the case where you want to plot all the datasets, you have extra `subscribe`. Here:

```
    locations.forEach((location: any) => {
            this.observationService.getAllByLocation(location)
  ---->       .subscribe(observations => {
                datasets.push(this.createDataset(observations));
              });
          });
```

which means that line:

```
  this.chart = new Chart('temperatureChart', { type: 'scatter', data: data, options: options });
```

will be called before `datasets` is filled with data.

One possible solution would be to add data series in the `subsribe` above like:

```
locations.forEach((location: any) => {
  this.observationService.getAllByLocation(location)
  .subscribe(observations => {
    this.chart.addSerie({
        data: this.createDataset(observations)
      },
      true,
      true);
  });
});
```

however, the resulting plot will be updated few times (you will have to wait until it loads fully)

Second one, you could create a chart once the `subsribe` is finished, like:

```
locations.forEach((location: any) => {
  this.observationService.getAllByLocation(location)
    .subscribe(observations => {
      datasets.push(this.createDataset(observations));
    },
      () => { /*error handling */},
      () => { /*observable is finished your datasets is filled 
with data, here you can create a graph*/});
});
```

Comment: No change in behaviour

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unable to get it working reliably after trying several different structures derived from your answer. At this point, I suspect my approach of loading the data with multiple consecutive calls could be the root of the problem and I'm going to look into redesigning that.